# Cant connect two Components in React-Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to export two Redux connected Components but it does not work.

At the App.jsx code like this:

```
export default {
    App: connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App),
    ConnectedList: connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)
  }
```

I connect two Components but the problem then is that the App is not recognized anymore in my index.js or the App was never exported, dunno Please advice.

```
   import React from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import store from "./js/store/configureStore";
    import App from "./js/components/App.jsx";
    // if you're in create-react-app import the files as:
    // import store from "./js/store/index";
    // import App from "./js/components/App.jsx";
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
ERROR Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 
        <App /> // 
      </Provider>,
      // The target element might be either root or app,
      // depending on your development environment
      // document.getElementById("app")
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Here´s my App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import List from "./List.jsx";
import Form from "./Form.jsx";
import Toasts from "./Toasts";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { addToast } from "../actions/index";
import { MDBNotification } from "mdbreact";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        const { addToast } = this.props.actions;
        addToast({ text: "Hello, World!" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <div className="row mt-5">
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <h2>Articles</h2>
                        <List />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <h2>Add a new article</h2>
                        <Form />
                    </div>
                    <Toasts />
                </div>
                <Toasts />
            </main>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    actions: PropTypes.shape({
        addToast: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }).isRequired
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators({ addToast }, dispatch)
});


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { badword: state.rootReducer.badword };
};

const ConnectedList = ({ badword }) => (
    <ul>
        var dd = badword;
        <MDBNotification
            show
            fade
            title="Bootstrap"
            message="Word is badword"
        text="11 mins ago"
        style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            right: 0
        }}
        />
      </ul>

);
export default {
    App: connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App),
    ConnectedList: connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it will work but you shouldn't export by default, and then import it like "import {App} from "./js/components/App";", I think it should work but I can't test this at the moment.

Comment: If I remove the `export` from `export default` I get error

Comment: Did you try doing like this;module.exports = {
  Color: Color,
  Animal: Animal
}

Comment: I dont undersand what that is I´m new to this

Comment: module.exports = { App: connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App), ConnectedList: connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)}

Comment: Thanks I get the same kind of error in index,js like ........./src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'App' is not exported from './js/components/App.jsx'..I put the app in curly b like this { App } but stil the same

Comment: I really want the class `ConnectedList` to be in the top-level App because `ConnectedList` will show popup notifications, I know the name is bad must change

Comment: Ok I can't solve the issue right now because I can't test it but if you want it on top level why don't you create these in different files and make a wrapper screen like HomeScreen and you can have 2 sub Components name HomeContent and and Notifications and after doing that you can export default your HomeScreen and import it in index.js between your providers.

Comment: That is what I try to do actually but for me it´s a learning curve, my brain get fried if I work faster:). Right now it´s the [notification](https://mdbootstrap.com) I try to learn